# Incremental variable in each iteration/loop in Jmeter Tests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, taurus

I have below setup for my test plan:

[image]

In POST http request, I am sending a variable myCount set to value 0.

As per above configuration,
this test will `run 100 times but everytime the value of myCount is sending 0`.

I want it in `incremental` 
`for example: for loop 1 value set to 1, for loop 2 value should set 2.`

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Also, I would like to know in Taurus as well.

Comment: You  can use Counter https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Thread Group has a [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) which returns the current iteration number, it's `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`

   [image]

   if you want the counting to start from 1 - go for [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)

   [image]
2. There is [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) which generates an incremented number each time it's being called

   [image]
3. There is Counter configuration element which does the same but you have additional possibility to control the number format, i.e. if you need `0001` instead of just `1` or you plan to re-use the generated variable value later on within the bounds of same request or iteration. More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)
4. With regards to Taurus - in case of [JMeter executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) it supports all the approaches mentioned above

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T.  Would be great if we get similar in Taurus yaml.